# Can't read from newly created file with content

Tags: c#

i am struggling with getting SHA256 sum of a file.
When program starts method `GetSHA256FromStream` is called.
The error occurs in method `GetSHA256` when `File.Open` is called.
I am running Visual Studio as Administrator.

ERROR:

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file
>  'C:\Users\WS1\AppData\Local\Temp\test.ttttt'
>  because it is being
> used by another process.'

I don't really know if i need to use async/await for working with files.

```
    public static string GetSHA256FromStream(Stream s)
    {
        string _tpath = Helper.GetTEMPPath("test.ttttt"); // %TEMP%\\test.ttttt
        Helper.WriteStreamToFile(s, _tpath);
        return Checksum.GetSHA256(_tpath, true);
    }

    public async static void WriteStreamToFile(Stream s, string outpath)
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream fStream = File.Open(outpath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
            s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            await s.CopyToAsync(fStream);
            fStream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    public static string GetSHA256(string text, bool isFile = false)
    {
        SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create();
        byte[] hash;
        if (isFile)
        {
            FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(text);
            hash = sha256.ComputeHash(stream);
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] textBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text);
            hash = sha256.ComputeHash(textBytes);
        }
        return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
    }
```

Comment: Place the FileStream creation within a using block, this ensures correct closure & disposal.

Comment: it seems it's already opened. as the message suggests! make sure to close the file before running `GetSHA256` you might have to inspect the OS's current open handles or restart, if you don't see the file opened on your computer

Comment: Change `WriteStreamToFile` to return a `Task`, and wait for it to complete in `GetSHA256FromStream` (which you would have to change to become async as well). Alternatively, use `s.CopyTo(fStream);` to ensure it completes before the method returns.

Comment: Changing to `s.CopyTo(fStream);` works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `WriteStreamToFile` is `async`, but you are not `await`ing it in `GetSHA256FromStream`. Thus, you are already calling `GetSHA256()` and trying to open the file, while `WriteStreamToFile` is still writing.

You could for instance make `GetSHA256FromStream` also async and then `await` writing to the file and then once that task is finished calculate the checksum

BTW, you should not return `void` on `async` methods but a `Task`

```
public static async Task<string> GetSHA256FromStream(Stream s)
{
    try {
        string _tpath = Helper.GetTEMPPath("test.ttttt"); // %TEMP%\\test.ttttt
        await Helper.WriteStreamToFile(s, _tpath);
        return Checksum.GetSHA256(_tpath, true);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        //some error logging
    } 
}

public async static Task WriteStreamToFile(Stream s, string outpath)
{
    try
    {
        FileStream fStream = File.Open(outpath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
        s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        await s.CopyToAsync(fStream);
        fStream.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Don't use empty catches but log some error here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, but `Checksum.GetSHA256` does not return a Task so it will not work, i think.

Comment: @XYZT did you try it? If `GetSHA256` returns a `string` and `GetSHA256FromStream` returns a `Task<string>` it will work ...

Comment: Ohh, Task<string>, that's the missing part, sorry.

Comment: @XYZT To be honest: I missed that part in the first version of that answer too ... :)